# find the number of occurance a number occur in between two number in python

Tags: python, count, range

```
    a = int(input())
    b = list(map(int,input().split()))
    n = []
    for i in range(b[0],b[1]):
        s = str(i)
        if(int(s[0])==a) or (int(s[1])==a):
           n.append(s)
    print(count(a))
```

I have some error in it.
for example:

a = 1

b = 10 20

output: 10

Because 1 occurs 10 times in between 10 t o 20.

Comment: Could you clarify what the original problem is?

Comment: If I got the question right, the answer for the input values in the body should be `11`  and not `10`.  That is because between `10` and `20`, the digit `1` occurs eleven times.

Comment: Oh gotcha,  I thought that "10 20" was somehow a string to count the characters of. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not quite clear, but here is a solution:

```py
digit = input()
a, b = map(int, input().split())

s = ''.join(str(_) for _ in range(a, b + 1))
print(s.count(digit))
```

The code above results in the following for inputs `1` and `10 20`:

```
11
```

If the upper limit should not be included, then the code is:

```py
digit = input()
a, b = map(int, input().split())

s = ''.join(str(_) for _ in range(a, b))
print(s.count(digit))
```

Which will output:

```
10
```

As you were expecting.

Finally, the count output can be done in just one pass with something like this:

```py
digit = input()
a, b = map(int, input().split())

print(''.join(str(_) for _ in range(a, b)).count(digit))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=str(input("a"))
start=int(input("start"))
end=int(input("end"))


occur=0
for i in range(start,end):
    occur+=str(i).count(a)
print(occur)
```

i have not tried it but if you modify the start and end a bit it should work